# Segfault with inheritence and casting

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, shared-ptr

I am using an existing `C++` which looks something like this

```
class Geometry {
public:
    enum {BOX, MESH} type;
    std::string name;
};

class Mesh : public Geometry {
public:
    std::string filename;
};

std::shared_ptr<Geometry> getGeometry() {
    std::shared_ptr<Geometry> geom = std::make_shared<Geometry>();
    geom->name = "geometry";

    Mesh *mesh = new Mesh();
    mesh->name = "name";
    mesh->filename = "filename";
    mesh->type = Geometry::MESH;
    geom.reset(mesh);

    return geom;
}
```

I need to extend the functionalities provided by these classes, so I have derived these two classes

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Geometry {
public:
    enum {BOX, MESH} type;
    std::string name;
};

class Mesh : public Geometry {
public:
    std::string filename;
};

std::shared_ptr<Geometry> getGeometry() {
    std::shared_ptr<Geometry> geom = std::make_shared<Geometry>();
    geom->name = "geometry";

    Mesh *mesh = new Mesh();
    mesh->name = "name";
    mesh->filename = "filename";
    mesh->type = Geometry::MESH;
    geom.reset(mesh);

    return geom;
}

class GeometryDerived : public Geometry {
public:
    void consumeGeometry() {
        Geometry geom = static_cast<Geometry>(*this);
        std::cout << geom.name << std::endl;
        if(geom.type == Geometry::MESH) {
            Mesh *mesh = static_cast<Mesh*>(&geom);
            std::cout << mesh->filename << std::endl;
            // mesh->get_output();
        }
    }
};

class MeshDerived : public Mesh {
public:
    std::string get_output() {
        return this->filename;        
    }
};



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Geometry> geom = getGeometry(); // this object is returned by the library

    std::shared_ptr<GeometryDerived> geomDerived = std::static_pointer_cast<GeometryDerived>(geom);
    geomDerived->consumeGeometry();

    return 0;
}
```

I get a `segfault` in line (in my actual code, its garbage string)

```
std::cout << mesh->filename << std::endl;
```

though other `int`s and `double`s are printed correctly. Even `geom.name` gets printed correctly. What is going on with strings here? What is the correct way to cast the objects here? Casting the object twice looks ugly. Below is the `GDB` output

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./cpp-example...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/user/cpp-example
name

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:383
383 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:383
#1  0x00007ffff7c247b2 in _IO_new_file_xsputn (n=140737488346512, data=0xdb8bbc853a3b3400, f=<optimized out>) at fileops.c:1236
#2  _IO_new_file_xsputn (f=0x7ffff7d7e6a0 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, data=0xdb8bbc853a3b3400, n=140737488346512) at fileops.c:1197
#3  0x00007ffff7c18541 in __GI__IO_fwrite (buf=0xdb8bbc853a3b3400, size=1, count=140737488346512, fp=0x7ffff7d7e6a0 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at libioP.h:948
#4  0x00007ffff7ed2824 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x0000555555556858 in GeometryDerived::consumeGeometry (this=0x55555556def0) at ../downcasting.cpp:23
#6  0x0000555555556513 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdec8) at ../downcasting.cpp:53
```

**Edit 1:**
The following changes works fine, but this is not what I want

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Geometry> geom = getGeometry();

    if(geom->type == Geometry::MESH) {
        std::shared_ptr<MeshDerived> meshDerived = std::static_pointer_cast<MeshDerived>(geom);
        std::cout << meshDerived->filename << std::endl;
    }

    // std::shared_ptr<GeometryDerived> geomDerived = std::static_pointer_cast<GeometryDerived>(geom);
    // geomDerived->consumeGeometry();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you believe is done by the line `Geometry geom = static_cast<Geometry>(*this);`? (If you are not trying to make a copy, why bother casting at all?)

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple issues with your code:

- In `GeometryDerived::consumeGeometry`, `Geometry geom = static_cast<Geometry>(*this);` creates a new object of type `Geometry` by [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) the current object. Later in that function, you do `Mesh *mesh = static_cast<Mesh*>(&geom);`, which returns an invalid pointer (as `geom` is not a `Mesh`). Accessing the data through that pointer is UB. (It will likely work for data members that are declared in `Geometry` on most implementations simply due to memory layout that is used by most compilers; that doesn't make the behavior well defined.)
- `static_pointer_cast` does not check that the pointed object is actually of the requested type. The cast will succeed even if the object is of a different type, but the returned pointer will be invalid. The `getGeometry` function returns a pointer to a `Mesh` object, which is unrelated to `GeometryDerived`, so the cast returns an invalid pointer.

---

A comment to the **Edit 1** part. No, this line is also wrong:

```
std::shared_ptr<MeshDerived> meshDerived = std::static_pointer_cast<MeshDerived>(geom);
```

The reason is the same as I noted above: `getGeometry` returns a pointer to `Mesh`, not `MeshDerived`. The code will probably work on most compilers because `MeshDerived` has the same memory layout as `Mesh`, but this is not a valid C++ nonetheless.

It looks like you want to "add methods" to an existing class in runtime. This is not possible in C++. Either you have to define the methods you need in the primary class (e.g. `Mesh`) or use a [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), i.e. define the new functionality in a separate class that will operate on `Mesh` etc. through its public members.

Comment: what do you mean slicing the object? But isn't that how you would downcast? And why do you say `geom` is not a `Mesh`? What about `geom.reset(mesh);`?

Comment: as for `static_pointer_cast`, I have stripped most of the code, but I have checks implemented.

Comment: @harsh See [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). `geom` is not a pointer, it is an object of type `Geometry`, the base class. By constructing it, you're discarding any data that was declared in the derived classes.

Comment: makes sense! Maybe I will have to go with the solution I mentioned in the edit

Comment: @harsh The point about the `static_pointer_cast` stands because the object you return from `getGeometry` is not `GeometryDerived`, it is a `Mesh`. So the cast returns an invalid pointer.

Comment: @harsh I've updated the answer to comment on your edit.